# Emulate dabbrev-expand in hippie-expand, limiting to matching buffers

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp, emacs24

If I use `dabbrev-expand` for expansion, Emacs searches the current buffer, then other buffers with the same mode. This is handled by `dabbrev-friend-buffer-function` which by default is set to `dabbrev--same-major-mode-p`.

This works fine, but I'd like to use `hippie-expand`.

```
(setq hippie-expand-try-functions-list
  '(try-expand-dabbrev
    try-expand-dabbrev-all-buffers))
```

This pulls completions from all buffers, even the buffers that don't match my current major mode.

How can I use `hippie-expand` with dabbrev completions only coming from buffers using the same major-mode as the current buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Sean's excellent suggestion (and assuming you have the [dash.el](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) list utility library installed):

```
(autoload '--filter "dash" nil t)

;; only consider buffers in the same mode with try-expand-dabbrev-all-buffers
(defun try-expand-dabbrev-matching-buffers (old)
  (let ((matching-buffers (--filter
                           (eq major-mode (with-current-buffer it major-mode))
                           (buffer-list))))
    (flet ((buffer-list () matching-buffers))
      (try-expand-dabbrev-all-buffers old))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty solution: Copy the source code of the function `try-expand-dabbrev-all-buffers` to a new location, rename it (say) `try-expand-dabbrev-all-buffers-same-mode`, and replace the expression `(buffer-list)` with the expression:

```
(remove-if-not (lambda (x) (eq major-mode (with-current-buffer x major-mode)))
               (buffer-list))
```

(You'll need to `(require 'cl)` to get `remove-if-not`, or else re-implement it in terms of `mapcar` and `delq`.)

Then, of course, replace `try-expand-dabbrev-all-buffers` with `try-expand-dabbrev-all-buffers-same-mode` in `hippie-expand-try-functions-list`.

You can get the source of `try-expand-dabbrev-all-buffers` using <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>.

Comment: Great idea. Since I don't plan to use `try-expand-dabbrev-all-buffers`, I can just use `defadvice` to make `(buffer-list)` return buffers based on your predicate.

Comment: That was my first thought, but advising such a fundamental function seems fraught with peril to me.

Comment: I agree it could go wrong (hopefully rarely). I've updated my answer to just call `try-expand-dabbrev-all-buffers` with `matching-buffers` redefined.